# Run command on shell and get output in vim

Tags: bash, shell, vim

I know how to run shell commands within vim using `:!r` and `:!`, but is there a way I can do that from outside, i.e. from bash?

Something along the lines of `vim 'ls -al'`. The output of `ls` should be in vim and editable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can read stdin

```
$ ls -al | vim -
```

Answer (score 6):

Execute the command the same way you would any command from the command line.

```
$ vim '+r !ls -al'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use bash process substitution like this:

```
vim <(ls -al)
```

See "Process Substitution" subsection of the bash manual:

```
man -P 'less +/Process\ Substitution' bash
```